# In-mem caching via Dynamic Programming

Tags: memory, dynamic-programming, cpu, memoization

How does Memoization table really help with perf benefits, when the CPU needs to access the RAM for already computed values? Was it not feasible to simply leave the computation to happen at CPU level always, without it having to access the RAM, even for the repeated values? CPU is pretty fast on its own right, against it accessing the RAM?

Comment: It depends how expensive re-computing would be, compared to a cache miss.  (Or a cache hit if you frequently call the same function with the same args.)  If you're memoizing (caching) something like the sum of an array, the computation itself would involve memory.

Comment: hmm does it involve ammortized complexity then always? whenever we specify the runtime BigO time complexity of any DP problem?

how does CPU Cache coherence play a role here exactly? Can the CPU cache cache the entire array, to avoid hitting RAM everytime, being contiguous & bringing in the spatial & temporal locality of reference into play?